# Audio not working in the android emulator (win7)

Tags: android, android-emulator

When starting my emulator from Eclipse or from the command line (Win7x32), I see no emulator window popup and the process hangs.

From the command-line, with `-verbose`, I see logs until the two lines:

```
emulator: using 'winaudio' audio input backend
emulator: using 'winaudio' audio output backend
```

... and then nothing.

When I start from the command line with `-verbose` and `-noaudio` options, the emulator starts up.

I can modify the Eclipse avd startup settings to have -noaudio, but I'd like to find a way to get audio working.

The commands `emulator -help-audio-in` and `emulator -help-audio-out` show `winaudio` and `winaudio` & `sdl`, available, respectively.

Does anyone have pointers as to how to get audio working with my emulator?

**Edit**
After this happened again, I discovered it was a faulty audio driver - basically a Windows audio driver issue.  Reinstalling the driver (and removing any usb-attached audio hardware like webcams, etc.) allowed the emulator to start w/o hanging @ winaudio statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As above, after this happened again, I discovered it was a faulty audio driver - basically a Windows audio driver issue.

Reinstalling the driver (and removing any usb-attached audio hardware like webcams, etc.) allowed the emulator to start w/o hanging @ `winaudio` statements.